# How to fill a vector with non-trivial initial values?

Tags: c++, stl

I know how to fill an std::vector with non-trivial initial values, e.g. sequence numbers:

```
void IndexArray( unsigned int length, std::vector<unsigned int>& v )
{
    v.resize(length);
    for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < length; ++i )
    {
        v[i] = i;
    }
}
```

But this is a for-loop. Is there an elegant way to do this with less lines of code using stl functionality (and **not** using Boost)?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use the generate algorithm, for a more general way of filling up containers:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

struct c_unique {
   int current;
   c_unique() {current=0;}
   int operator()() {return ++current;}
} UniqueNumber;


int main () {
  vector<int> myvector (8);
  generate (myvector.begin(), myvector.end(), UniqueNumber);

  cout << "\nmyvector contains:";
  for (vector<int>::iterator it=myvector.begin(); it!=myvector.end(); ++it)
    cout << " " << *it;

  cout << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

This was shamelessly lifted and edited from [cplusplusreference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/generate.html).

Comment: He may want to start with v[i] == i but change it later in the code.

Comment: yes probably, i was hoping he'd explain the case. there may possibly be a better method than filling em up first. Like a lazy evaluation-ish way or something.

Comment: I made my question more general, since the question was really about initializing with non-trivial values. I indeed wanted to fill the array with index numbers, to be able to permute them later. There probably will be other solutions to that as well.

Comment: right, removed the question. Perhaps you can post that permutation question? The solution might be interesting :)

Comment: @moog NOTE: generate may make a _copy_ or copies of the function you provide it, this code might generate the sequence "1 1 1 1 ..".  Instead, use tr1::ref to pass a reference-wrapper that refers to UniqueNumber, to avoid copies:  generate(..  tr1::ref(UniqueNumber) );

Answer (score 5):

I usually go with `std::generate` plus a simple generator:

```
template <typename T>
struct gen {
    T x;
    gen(T seed) : x(seed) { }

    T operator ()() { return x++; }
};

generate(a.begin(), a.end(), gen<int>(0));
```

Answer (score 4):

If you're using SGI STL (or a derivative, such as STLPort), you can use [`iota`](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/iota.html). :-)

```
void IndexArray(unsigned int length, vector<unsigned int>& v)
{
    vector<unsigned int>(length).swap(v);
    iota(v.begin(), v.end(), 0);
}
```

Comment: Also present in c++11

Answer (score 2):

There is also a `iota()` function in [adobe.ASL](http://stlab.adobe.com/group__iota.html), (and a [value_iterator](http://stlab.adobe.com/classadobe_1_1value__iterator.html) as well).
In boost, there is a [counting_iterator](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/libs/iterator/doc/counting_iterator.html), and I suspect a few other ways to do generate number sequences on the fly in boost.

Answer (score 1):

I know this has already been answered, but I prefer the "fill" function in the algorithm library, since it's seems more intuitive for me to read:

```
// fill algorithm example
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main () {
  vector<int> myvector (8);                       // myvector: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

  fill (myvector.begin(),myvector.begin()+4,5);   // myvector: 5 5 5 5 0 0 0 0
  fill (myvector.begin()+3,myvector.end()-2,8);   // myvector: 5 5 5 8 8 8 0 0

  cout << "myvector contains:";
  for (vector<int>::iterator it=myvector.begin(); it!=myvector.end(); ++it)
    cout << " " << *it;

  cout << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

This too was also shamelessly lifted from [cplusplusreference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/fill/).

Comment: How would you use this to fill a vector with progressive numbers as asked?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a C style array you can use std:copy, e.g.,

```
int c_array[] = {3,4,5};

const int* pbegin = &c_array[0];
const size_t c_array_size = sizeof(c_array) / sizeof(c_array[0]);
const int* pend  = pbegin + c_array_size;

std::vector<int> v;
v.reserve(c_array_size);
std::copy(pbegin, pend, std:back_inserter(v));
```